# Weighted random choice: Generate a list of "n" words respecting the frequencies in a .txt file randomly

Tags: python, list, cpu-word

I have a text file with 500 words and their respective frequencies.

I need a code that randomly generates a list of "n" words respecting the frequencies in the text file.

The .txt is this one:

[palabrasyfrecuencias.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bwiOpjSf6wTf4U3nLR5wpzaGVmPBDnwF/view?usp=sharing)

I'm using this code to read the file:

```
pd.read_fwf('palabrasyfrecuencias.txt', header=None, names=["Núm. orden", "Palabras", "Frecuencia"])
```

And this is the result I have right now:

[image]

**Any help is welcome. Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple number generator trick leveraging cumulative probabilities will do the trick. (Forgive me if I messed up el Español).

```
import random
import pandas as pd

pd.read_fwf('palabrasyfrecuencias.txt', header=None, names=["Núm. orden", "Palabras", "Frecuencia"])
sum(df["Frecuencia"])

# This is actually a count, not a frequency
df["Contar"] = df["Frecuencia"]

# Compute the frequencies as a proportion of the total seen words
df["Frecuencia"] = df["Contar"] / sum(df["Contar"])

# Compute the cumulative distribution
df["Frecuencia_Acumulada"] = df['Frecuencia'].cumsum()


def generate_word(df):
    """
    Generate a word according to the provided cumulative distribution using a random number
    generator.

    Args:
        None
    Returns:
        The generated word
    """
    rand = random.random()

    # The first cumulative frequency in the range is the word we're looking for
    return df[df["Frecuencia_Acumulada"] > rand]["Palabras"].iloc[0]

# Generate N words
N = 10
generated_words = [generate_word(df) for _ in range(N)]
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the response. I'm having an error in generated_words line: **NameError: name 'generate_word' is not defined**. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: You're running a script in the interpreter. It's referring to a function you haven't defined at that point. Define the `generate_word` function just after the import statements instead of at the end.

Comment: Thanks. Once I print **print(generated_words)**, I'm getting a list of "None" Values:
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]. We're close!

Comment: What I see after running the script three times:

% python3 script.py
['quiere', 'pensar', 'hacer', 'todas', 'si', 'creo', 'venga', 'primer', 'gracias', 'ma�ana']
% python3 script.py
['d�a', 'hacer', 'buscando', 'quer�a', 'eguridad', 'haber', 'c�mo', 'reocupes', 'necesito', 'cada']
% python3 script.py
['c�mo', 'misma', 'voy', 'sabe', 'hacer', 'tal', 'si', 'despu�s', 's�', 'd�a']

Comment: Thanks Eric!! Now is running fine!